# Condensing nested loops

Tags: c++, c, loops, for-loop, optimization

I'm trying to convert these 3 loops:

```
for (a = 1; a < amax; a++) {
    for (b = 1; b < bmax; b++) {
        for (c = 1; c < cmax; c++) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

to a single loop.

I've tried this:

```
for (abc = 0; abc < (amax * bmax * cmax); ++abc)
{
    a = abc / (bmax * cmax) + 1;
    b = (abc % (bmax * cmax)) / cmax + 1;
    c = (abc % (bmax * cmax)) % cmax + 1;

    ...
}
```

however it is not equivalent. Where's the logic error?

Comment: `b = (abc % (bmax * cmax)) / cmax + 1;` should be `b = (abc % (amax * cmax)) / cmax + 1;` Likewise for c: `c = (abc % (amax * bmax)) % cmax + 1;` Discalaimer: not saying they are now equivalent (maybe more errors).

Comment: Isn't adding a bunch of divisions more of a pessimization? And it's a hell of a lot less readable to boot.

Comment: @DanMašek yes, it's usually a bad idea however this was a needed hack since I want use OpenMP parallel for (and OpenMP 2.0 does not support the collapse operator).

Answer (score 2):

The `a` loop has `amax-1` iterations, not `amax` iterations. Ditto for the `b` and `c` loops. So, the single loop should have `(amax-1)*(bmax-1)*(cmax-1)` iterations.

To extract the `a`, `b` and `c` values treat the single loop index as a mixed base number (the bases you multiplied to find the number of iterations), that is, simple integer division and remainder operations.

Add 1 to each of the resulting values.

Answer (score 1):

Your first loop runs far less than second loop.

Imagine

```
int amax = 3;
int bmax = 3;
int cmax = 3;
```

Your first loop has 2, 2, 2 = 8 iterations.

Second loop will run through 0 to < `(3 * 3* 3 = 27)` i.e. `27` times

Also there are few more issues in the computation of a,b,c checkout the following/ Notice abc starts at 1 and the condition is `<=`:- 
(Code in c - haven't touched c++ since ages)

```
   int x = 1;
   amax-=1; 
   bmax-=1; 
   cmax-=1;

    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;
    for (int abc = 1; abc <= (amax * bmax * cmax); ++abc)
    {
        c = abc % cmax;
        c = c != 0 ? c : cmax;

        var m = ' a='+a+' b='+b+' c='+c+'  ::::'+(x++);
        printf("%s\n", m); 


        a = abc < (bmax*cmax) || abc % ((bmax*cmax)) != 0 ? a : (a + 1) % amax;
        a = a != 0 ? a : amax;
        b = abc < cmax || abc % (cmax) != 0 ? b : (b + 1) % bmax;
        b = b != 0 ? b : bmax;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any mileage to be gained from using `div()` from `<stdlib.h>`?  `div_t r1 = div(abc, (bmax * cmax); div_t r2 = div(r1.rem, cmax);`?